# Can this quadratic program be solved analyticaly?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-programming

I have a convex quadratic program wich is structured as follows : 
    \begin{align*}
 \operatorname{argmin}_{p}   &\hspace{0.5em} p' A p  - 2 p' b \\
 \mathrm{s.t.}   &\hspace{0.5em} Ep=f \\
 & \hspace{0.5em} p_i \ge 0 \;\forall i
 \end{align*}

Some hypothesis :

- The matrix $A$ is a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix, with diagonal elements strictly positives and summing to one (it is then pos def and invertible)
- The vector $b$ is non-negative
- The matrix $E$ is a $m\times n$ matrix such that $m<n$, making the number of constraints smaller than the number of variables. Elements in $E$ are inside $[0,1]$. The dimension of the affine subspace spanned by $Ep=f$ is $n-m$.
- The solution of the unconstraint QP, $p^* = A^{-1}b$, is positive (inside the inequality constraints) but *not* inside the constraint $Ep = f$.
- I do know a point, let's call it $p_{eq}$, such that $Ep_{eq}  = f$ and such that $p_{ep,i} \ge 0\; \forall i$.
- $\operatorname{diag}(p_{eq}) = A^{-1}$
- If you look closely at the previous points, you'll see that we have a convex problem, whithin a non-empty convex domain, and hence existence and unicity of a minimum.

Some of these informations might not be relevant, and some might, so i gave you all i have ;)

I know i can reexpress the problem by using the block matrix $[[A,E'],[E,0]]$, but this did not help me.

What do you think? Will these hypothesis be enough to find a closed-form expression for the solution? If no closed-form solution, can you think of a smarter way of solving it than using a standard QP solver?

Edit : A similar problem was asked a few years back, but with less hypothesis (more general), and the answer was No, see [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/771828/equality-constrained-quadratic-program?rq=1). My question is, are the hypothesis i have changing this or not. Especialy, i think that the fact that the (unconstraint) optimal solution fullfills the inequality constraint and that we have a point fullfilling all constraints (but not the minimum) might be relevant.

Comment: Hi, there's a small typo at the end of the sentence at the third point: it should be "Elements", not "El**l**ements".

Comment: Thanks for the typo. You know that you can correct it yourself ? Usualy it's good practice to correct it directly.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I also know that +2 points of reputation are awarded for this, if the edit is accepted. However, when the changes are few and very small, I prefer to tell the Author of the post: to me it is a nonsense to get experience points for correcting insignificant typos on a research level mathematics web site.

Comment: Did not now for the points. Makes sense now. Thanks anyway

Comment: Does the solution of the KKT system (as shown in the linked question) also satisfy the inequalities?

Comment: @fibonatic No !